# Magento 2: How to enable html tags in backend attributes?

Tags: magento2.2, attributes

I have added payment method in magento2.2. The payment method has an input box typed textarea. I want to add a href link but it's not supporting it. Is there a way to enable HTML tags.
[image]

I am getting this in frontend

[image]

Comment: Please add code how you get value at front end?

Comment: It's a 3rd party module, I just want to enable html tags for instruction @RohanHapani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there was a similar question answered on Magento SE a few days ago, I would like to answer it.

As I understood you want to add some HTML tags to a custom payment method.

By default Magento `escapeHtml` when rendering the instructions for the payment methods.

We need to Create a small module which will override `getInstructions` function. For reference, I assume that the name of custom payment method module is Company_CustomModule

let's create a module `Stack_Instructions`.

> app/code/Stack/Instructions/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Stack_Instructions',
__DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Stack/Instructions/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Stack_Instructions" setup_version="1.0.0">
   </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Stack/Instructions/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Company\CustomModule\Model\InstructionsConfigProvider" type="Stack\Instructions\Model\Rewrite\InstructionsConfigProvider" />
</config>
```

> app/code/Stack/Instructions/Model/Rewrite/InstructionsConfigProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Stack\Instructions\Model\Rewrite;

class InstructionsConfigProvider extends \Company\CustomModule\Model\InstructionsConfigProvider

{
    public function getInstructions($code)
    {
        return nl2br($this->methods[$code]->getInstructions());// removed escapeHtml function!
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad to know that my answer helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the  3rd party payment module name is "**Company_MyModule**"

Please find the config provider class of your 3rd party payment module. In general, this class exists under Company/MyModule/Model/ and class names may be ConfigProvider

Once you identify the **ConfigProvider class**, you may try to update the class as follows.

**Note:**
Basically, you need to update the ConfigProvider class to insert a dependency for ***\Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider*** which will help to Parse the config field value.

I assume the ConfigProvider class name is **ConfigProvider.php** under folder **app/code/Company/MyModule/Model/**

Update the class as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Company\MyModule\Model;

.................

use Magento\Checkout\Model\ConfigProviderInterface;
.................


/**
 * Class ConfigProvider
 */
final class ConfigProvider implements ConfigProviderInterface
{

   ................    
   protected $templateProcessor;
   ................



    public function __construct(
    ................ ,
    ................ ,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\Template\FilterProvider $templateProcessor     
    )
    {
        ................
        $this->templateProcessor = $templateProcessor;
        ................

    }



    /**
     * Retrieve assoc array of checkout configuration
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfig()
    {        

        $configArray = [
            'payment' => [
                self::CODE => [
                    'active' => ......,
                    'title' => ....,
                    'instructions' => $this->filterOutputHtml('SYSTEM-CONFIG-VALUE-FOR-instructions'),

                ]
            ]
        ];
        return $configArray;
    }


    public function filterOutputHtml($string)
 {
    return $this->templateProcessor->getPageFilter()->filter($string);
  }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you and I just wanted to know where can I find this file ConfigProvider.php in vendor?

Comment: I want to update it for Magento payment method also

Comment: You can find it using your module name. can you confirm your 3rd party module is under the vendor directory? if yes look for the company name . Thank you